# Monitoring and checking status of YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

How can I access to YARN metrics such as status of resource manager and node manager?
Moreover, the same question about running yarn containers.  I would like to do it via web interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Yarn Resource Manager UI](http://hadooptutorial.info/yarn-web-ui/), which is usually accessible at port 8088 of your resource manager (although the port can be configured). Here you get an overview over your cluster.

Details about the nodes of the cluster can be found in this UI in the *Cluster* menu, submenu *Nodes*. Here one finds the health information, some information about the hardware, currently running jobs and the software version of the node manager. For more details, you would have to log into each node and check the nodemanager logs (for the node where the resource manager is running, this log is also available via *Tools* menu -> *Local logs*, but this would not be sufficient if you have more than one node in your cluster).

More details about the Resource manager (including runtime statistics) are available in the *Tools* menu -> *Server metrics*.

If you want to access these information programatically, you can use the [Resource Manager's REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html).

Another option might be to use [Ambari](https://ambari.apache.org/). This tools is an Hadoop management tool that can be used to monitor the different services within an Hadoop cluster and to trigger alerts in case of unusual or unexpected events. However, it requires some installation and configuration efforts.

Comment: However, Where can I find information about node manager and resource manager?